# Conditional Copy of one element from one column and apply to respective rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, series

In my following data frame, I want to create a new column 'refer' with code_num for its associated primary_fruit, if it is not associated with priamry_fruit it should be left blank.

```
dct = {'Store': ('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'),
       'code_num':(101,102,103,104,105,106,201,202,203),
       'fruits': ('apple','cherry','cherry, apple','banana','cherry','rambo','apple, cherry','banana','toy')
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)


fruit_list= ["apple","banana","cherry"]
primary_fruit = 'banana'

print(df)

Store code_num     fruits
A     101          apple  
A     102          cherry 
A     103          cherry,apple 
A     104          banana 
A     105          cherry 
A     106          rambo  
B     201          apple,cherry
B     202          banana
B     203          toy
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
Store code_num    fruits       reference
A     101          apple         104
A     102          cherry        104
A     103          cherry,apple  104
A     104          banana        104
A     105          cherry        104
A     106          rambo       
B     201          apple,cherry  202
B     202          banana        202
B     203          toy
```

In my current ask I don't want value in 106 and 203 as they are not part of 'fruit_list'

I have tried below code but it is just picking up the reference number for only primary_fruit (104 & 202) rest all are left blank

```
unique_store_id = df.Store.unique()

for store_id in unique_store_id:
    s = (df.Store == store_id) & df['fruits'].isin(unique_all_parts)   
    primary_code = df[df['fruits']==first_primary]['code_num']
    df.loc[s,'reference'] = primary_code
```

Thank you for the help :)

**UPDATE:**
Suggestion of @Scott Boston is working well on the complete dataset. But in the case of slicing/dicing it is giving a [KeyError: 'None'], I will have to use this logic to be applied on slicing data frame for each store where "fruit_list" and "primary_fuit" will be changed.  (I should have to include in the original question my apologies.)
Concept: Based on primary fruit for each store, the code-num should be provided in reference

Comment: Let me know if I have to re-ask the question since requirement is updated. I am sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dct = {'Store': ('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B'),
       'code_num':(101,102,103,104,105,106,201,202,203),
       'fruits': ('apple','cherry','cherry, apple','banana','cherry','rambo','apple, cherry','banana','toy')
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dct)


fruit_list= ["apple","banana","cherry"]
primary_fruit = 'banana'

m = df.set_index(['Store', 'code_num'])['fruits'].str.split(',').explode().isin(fruit_list).max(level=[0,1]).to_numpy()

df['primary_code'] = df.loc[df['fruits'] == primary_fruit, 'code_num']

#Changed this line
df['reference'] = df.groupby('Store')['primary_code'].transform(lambda x: x.loc[x.first_valid_index()]).where(m, '')

df_out = df.drop('primary_code', axis=1)
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
  Store  code_num         fruits reference
0     A       101          apple       104
1     A       102         cherry       104
2     A       103  cherry, apple       104
3     A       104         banana       104
4     A       105         cherry       104
5     A       106          rambo          
6     B       201  apple, cherry       202
7     B       202         banana       202
8     B       203            toy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate! I did try this logic but I am receiving below error:
```TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'```
Also, in my actual dataset store is int64, the problem persisted even though I converted the column to (str) type. Any idea?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?   Does this exact code produce this error?

Comment: I have pandas 1.1.1. and No this exact code is perfectly executing on the example dataset I shared above. However, I am having trouble when I am using this code for my actual project, I have ensured there no null values in the respective columns and also converted store number to str. I am having hard time :(

Comment: Check the dtype of the code_num column. change it to int if you can.

Comment: I am really sorry for the trouble. @Scott Boston. Eventually, I have to make it work it for string value, being a newbie to python I am having a hard time figuring. But I appreciate your help here. :)
BTW elements code_num looks something like this 'INC1234567' and similar.

Comment: @nealkaps Okay... I changed the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221187/discussion-between-nealkaps-and-scott-boston).